# Kolmogorov distance

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution

Can someone provide an example of direct me to an example of a problem where Kolmogorov distance is used.  I think I understand the definition but would like to see an illustration to solidify my understanding and can't find anything.  I am currently studying it as a way to measure the distance between a given distribution and the normal distribution.

Comment: Yes, the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, I have used and I can say it is efficient...

Answer (score 0):

In the classical Glivenko-Cantelli Theorem. It states the following: if $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ are iid random variables with common cdf $F(x)$ and $F_n(x)$ is the empirical cdf defined as 
$$
F_n(x)=\dfrac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nI(X_i\leq x),
$$
then, 
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|F_n(x)-F(x)|\overset{a.s.}{\longrightarrow}0,\quad n\to\infty.
$$
This states that $F_n(x)$ approaches $F(x)$ uniformly with probability one whenever the sample size tends to infinity, i.e., the Kolmogorov distance between $F_n(x)$ and $F(x)$ converges to zero with probability one.